# DBPedia Sparql with one request get links for multiple resources

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Currently I'm doing for every entity that I have a single request to the sparql endpoint to get all the links for it e.g.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
   {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/San_Francisco> rdf:type ?link}
}
```

I want to make it more efficient, and I would like to know if there is a way to get the links for multiple entities with one request. I threw something together but this gives me just a big list with all the links.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/San_Francisco> rdf:type ?link}
    UNION
    {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Silicon_Valley> rdf:type ?link}
}
```

Can I somehow get the links, so I can identify to which entity they belong?

Comment: was it distinct results that you wanted?

Comment: No I didn't need distinct results, your first suggestion solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be a little more succinct with the **SPARQL 1.1** `values` keyword:

```
SELECT  *
WHERE
  { VALUES ?entity { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/San_Francisco>
        <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Silicon_Valley> }
    ?entity  rdf:type  ?link
  }
```

Do you want a distinct list?  Maybe sort the list and add English-language labels if available?

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?link ?llab
WHERE
  { VALUES ?entity { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/San_Francisco>
        <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Silicon_Valley> }
    ?entity  rdf:type  ?link
    OPTIONAL
      { ?link  rdfs:label  ?llab
        FILTER ( lang(?llab) = "en" )
      }
  }
ORDER BY ?link
```